# Path constraints problem

Tags: modeling, animation, workflow, path

I'm a beginner 3d modeler and animator that wish to take my animations more seriously this year. I wish to attempt at making a simple walk cycle that's following a path. But when I do path constraints my model is somewhere that I can't even find. I tried shift s on one of the vertices on the path and my armature model, didn't work. I used the follow path option, also didn't work. I'm not sure if it's the location that's the problem or I mess up on something, but anyone have any ideas what it is?
I looked up this issue, but they didn't help much either and that most of the solutions are mostly old.[image]
Sorry, if I'm asking too much, I'm just really confused.
I'm not sure how to add a second image, but here what it looks like when I do path constraints.

Comment: I have seen your question and it is okay. It shows you have at least shown some effort. As for the problem, I have found the solution. Just click on the link below and it will show how to use a path constraint and show a walk cycle. Here it is: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L2EaqaMr6Eg

Comment: You may want to follow the dotted blue line, your model seems to be way up there. Make sure to remove all transforms from the base object before using the constraint, otherwise they are added together

Comment: https://youtu.be/L2EaqaMr6Eg

Comment: @Gorgious How do I remove the transforms? Like the bone metarig and apply them so they can turn into 0? Well, I try that and it hasn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Basically the constrained object (a mesh, a bone, an empty) has to be set (or keyframed) in the world origin location (0,0,0) when the follow path constraint is set up, so that in the first frame of the constrained action it will be exactly where the first point of the path is, and in the last on the last.

If you still have offset problems and you don't want to change your elements you can create  an empty, set it as path constrained, and parent the root bone of your armature to the empty, then move the root bone to the appropriate location on the first frame.

Comment: Hello, i believe I followed what you said and hopefully add a path contranstrant but now my model isn't allign with my path. Is there a certain option im missing. I posted a new question that shows it and even render an animation, but not sure if I can post it.

Comment: In the follow path constraint there is a "Follow curve" option to check, then you'll have to choose the correct up and forward axes. Be sure to have all loc rot and scale applied (Ctrl A) to avoid unexpected behaviours.